# Issue while connecting Node service with Office365 mail exchange server

Tags: node.js, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm facing issues while trying to read mail from Office 365 account. Below is the code I'm using:

```
const EWS = require('node-ews');

// exchange server connection info 
const ewsConfig = { username: 'myuser@myDomain.com', password: 'mypassword', host: 'https://outlook.office365.com/owa/myDomain.com/', auth: 'basic' };

// initialize node-ews 
const ews = new EWS(ewsConfig);

// define ews api function 
const ewsFunction = 'ExpandDL';

// define ews api function args 
const ewsArgs = { 'Mailbox': { 'EmailAddress':'publiclist@domain.com' } };

// query EWS and print resulting JSON to console 
ews.run(ewsFunction, ewsArgs).then(result => { 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); }).catch(err => { 
  console.log(err.message); });
```

Comment: What issues?  what errors?  You show code but y ou don't actually explain what problem(s) you're having.

Comment: It is not clear whether you have got an exception or error message...

Answer (score 0):

Your EWS config is wrong for Office365, the EWS endpoint for Office365 is https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx so you should just have

```
const ewsConfig = { username: 'myuser@myDomain.com', password: 'mypassword', host: 'https://outlook.office365.com', auth: 'basic' };
```

Comment: Have tried your suggested code, but I am getting error "Basic Auth StatusCode 401: Unauthoized" though using valid email/password.  If using host: 'https://outlook.office365.com/owa/myDomain.com/' then getting Invalid or malformed wsdl file . Any help is appreciated.